# Passing value in IXLWorksheet convert string to date

Tags: c#, excel

I have an excel builder with IXLWorksheet.
When I try to pass the values decimal to the excel worksheet, it convert thes numbers 3.10,3.11 and 3.12 into date.
I really don't have an idea why is this happening, someone know?

Print Example:

1. 4.30 converts normal
2. 3.10 turns into datetime.

[image]

Comment: I just tested with 4,10 and it also changed to datetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this to resolve:

ws.Cell(vLinha, coluna).SetValue(Convert.ToString(propertyValue));